# How to import multiple images from assets folder

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working with web pack and trying to import multiple images to JavaScript from the folder they are located in but not sure how to do it all together. The code below works but only for importing one image at a time.

I have thought of making an array and putting all images in there but it did not work.

import img1 from "./assets/1.JPG";

$(function(){
    $('#photos').html(`<figure><img src = ${img1}></figure>`);
});

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways.

You can use require (a static method)

```
<img src={`${require('./assets/1.JPG')}`} />
```

OR,
You can use `require.context` (*recommended*).

Check: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext